# Can i use database first approach with entity framework inside asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-database-first

I want to start a new asp.net core MVC web project, but i am but sure if i can follow the database first approach? by creating the database inside my sql server >> then map the database inside my application using entity framework (as we used to do in asp.net mvc-5)?
Thanks

Comment: For Existing database in EF Core, you could refer to these tutorials : https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database or https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx

Answer (score 0):

yes u can use something like this on **Package Manager Console** or **any other Console**

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=IPADDRESS;Database=DBNAME;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --context-dir Context -o Entities -f
```